# How to convert a Varbinary value to a string format or readable format

Tags: python, sql

I tried with similar questions but no luck, can someone help me with this.

trying in SQL and python.

in SQL

```
declare @b2 VARBINARY(MAX) 
set @b2 = 0X636....
SELECT CONVERT(nVARCHAR(max), @b2, 0);
```

> > getting in some chinese

```
from IO import stringIO
s = 0x636...

print(stirngIO.stringIO(s).getvalue())
print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

can someone help

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Convert is a product specific function.)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is asking us to guess at the encoding being used. If you show us a bit more of the binary data than `0X636` and also what you are expecting to see as output, we might be able to help. As it is, you haven't told us enough. Please [edit] your question to provide additional details.